# Execute User submitted sql safely

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to execute a user submitted sql code in my server (for teaching purposes). But this can be very dangerous.
I want to know what will be better, if execute the sql code (if there is a secure way to do this) or only check if the user code matches a regular expression and show a symbolic result.

Comment: Which programming language do you use? What have you tried? You need to give us more, than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and most basic thing you can do is limit the account used by the webpage in the first place.

Give the specific account only privileges to do specific things to only a specific database. Disable all I/O to disk and other such features as well.

Be definition though, **you must allow some insert, create, delete, update statements**.

Furthermore three options:

### Create a complete webapp

Additionally, if possible I would give each user their own account, that is sandboxed from all the rest of the schemas.

You could create a web application that:

- manages the user accounts (registration, etc).
- creates separate databases for each user.
- manages the permissions to sandbox each user in their own schema.
- Provides an environment for running queries.

### Provide them access to PHP My Admin

Give your students access to PHPMyAdmin, but without an administrator password.
Each student will have his own username, and access to their own database with specific permissions.

### Limit Users to only Using Select

If your teaching something as basic as select statements, and joins, you can give the specific account used by the web interface only privileges for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would never execute arbitrary code from a user on my database unless it was a database treated as nothing but a sandbox - no "real" data, tables, anything. I'd assume that it'd constantly be dumped and d. As long as that's met though, I don't see how you're going to get results as realistic for teaching as just doing it for real.